# How do I solve Question 42, Level 5 in Think Different?

Tags: think-different

I'm a bit stuck on Question 42, Level 5, which has the following number puzzle:

```
53 (3) 59
92 (4) 98
34 (2) 38
71 (?) 79
```

I know I need to solve for the question mark, but I'm not sure what the pattern is or even where to start. Does anyone know what to do?

[image: Question 42, Level 5]

Comment: Note that while we can help, we like to see prior effort by the asker. That way, we don't feel like we're being used.

Comment: This question could also have worked on https://puzzling.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have numbers X, Y, and Z, it looks like the trick is to

> multiply the second digit of X by Y then append the result to the first digit of X to get Z. 
>  50 + (3 * 3) = 59 
>  90 + (2 * 4) = 98 
>  30 + (2 * 4) = 38

If this is the case, the answer is

> ? = 9

Answer (score 1):

9.

Take the last digit of the numbers and divide the right number by the left one.

```
53 (3) 59 -> 3 9 -> 9 / 3 = 3  
92 (4) 98 -> 2 8 -> 8 / 2 = 4  
34 (2) 38 -> 4 8 -> 8 / 4 = 2  
71 (?) 79 -> 1 9 -> 9 / 1 = 9
```